# Como pegar input usando HTML e JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Como novato na linguagem 'JS', gostaria de saber como, simplesmente, pegar texto de um `<form>` (sem encaminhar para outra página e sem alterar a URL) e passar para uma função como `alert()` quando o usuário der enter no `<input>` (text/password) ou clicar no `<input>` (submit).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nesse exemplo simples, é possível resolver tratando apenas o evento `submit` do próprio formulário:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <input type="text" id="campo">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

```
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
var campo = document.getElementById('campo');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // alerta o valor do campo
    alert(campo.value);

    // impede o envio do form
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkxzf/

Comment: Ganhou o premio resposta correta pelo 403 do Michael :)

Answer (score 8):

No código Javascript abaixo (não usei jQuery), existem dois eventos: um para detectar a tecla  no momento em que o valor é digitado no `input`, e outro para detectar o clique no botão "Enviar".

### HTML:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="meu-input" />
    <input type="submit" id="meu-submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

### Javascript:

```
// Função que mostra o valor do input num alert
function mostrarValor() {
    alert(document.getElementById("meu-input").value);
}

// Evento que é executado toda vez que uma tecla for pressionada no input
document.getElementById("meu-input").onkeypress = function(e) {
    // 13 é a tecla <ENTER>. Se ela for pressionada, mostrar o valor
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        mostrarValor();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

// Evento que é executado ao clicar no botão de enviar
document.getElementById("meu-submit").onclick = function(e) {
    mostrarValor();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUs87/3/)

Comment: Michael, seu exemplo está dando Forbbiden 403. Acho que alert() é alertado como algum tipo de XSS no JSFiddle

Comment: É que faltou previnir o envio do formulário.

Comment: Ah sim, mancada. É o sono! =) Em todo caso, estou testando aqui e ao adicionar o `e.preventDefault();` acontecem umas coisas estranhas (o campo é zerado, ou o alert não aparece). Será que ele só dá para usar o `preventDefault` com `addEventListener`? Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/MUs87/4/

Comment: O `preventDefault()` que você usa no `keydown` funcionou normalmente para mim. O outro eu acho que não funciona porque você precisa previnir o evento `submit` do formulário, não do botão.

Comment: Ah sim, era isso mesmo, obrigado! Além disso, o keydown com o preventDefault estava fazendo aparecer dois alerts em sequência para mim. Mudei para keypress e ficou legal. Vou atualizar a resposta (embora sua solução esteja obviamente melhor)