# Pegar valores do Input e inserir no Onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

tenho um formulário e preciso que ao clicar no botão, eu envie parâmetros do que foi digitado nos campos input dentro da url função do onclick:

```
<form action="whatsapp.php" id="send-whatsapp" target="_blank" method="get"> 
    <input name="login" type="hidden" value="logindousuario">
    <input name="numero" type="hidden" value="numero">
    <input type="text" name="nome"  placeholder="Nome"> 
    <input type="text" name="telefone" class="telephoneMask"  placeholder="(00) 0000-0000"> 
    <input type="submit" value="" class="enviar" onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('https://site.com.br/whatsapp.php?login=valordoinput&numero=valordoinput&nome=valordoinput&telefone=valordoinput')">
</form>
```

Podem me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Precisa ser necessariamente no onclick? Você pode pegar os valores dos inputs colocando uma classe ou id. Se puder ser assim, tem uma resposta que pode te ajudar nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21860/como-pegar-input-usando-html-e-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi o seu código, você quer mandar parâmetros para um link externo no mesmo momento em que posta dados do formulário para a página interna whatsapp.php. Você pode tentar fazer isso com jquery, primeiro acessar o link, e se receber um retorno, postar o formulário. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="whatsapp.php" id="send-whatsapp" target="_blank" method="POST"> 
 <input name="login" id="login" type="hidden" value="logindousuario">
 <input name="numero" id="numero" type="hidden" value="numero">
 <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"  placeholder="Nome"> 
 <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" class="telephoneMask"  placeholder="(00) 0000-0000"> 
 <input type="button" onclick="enviarFormulario()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function enviarFormulario(){
var dados = {
login: $("#login").val(),
numero: $("#numero").val(),
nome: $("#nome").val(),
telefone: $("#telefone").val()
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://site.com.br/whatsapp.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: dados,
    datatype: 'text'
})
.done(function (data) { 
  $("#send-whatsapp").submit();
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
//Tratar o erro
});
}

</script>
```

Agora, caso o seu link seja interno (eu vi que as duas páginas compartilham o mesmo nome), pode pensar em algo mais simples, enviar o formulário usando o método POST e deixar que a página whatsapp.php faça a leitura dos dados (usando $_POST)

Answer (score 1):

Fazer essa lógica *inline*  parece-me pouco prático e difícil de ler... o melhor é usar uma função que chama essa funçao

Ou seja, por exemplo:

```js
function onSubmit(form, btn) {

  btn.disabled = true; // bloquear o botão para não enviar multiplas vezes

  const campos = ['login', 'numero', 'nome', 'telefone'];
  const queryString = campos
    .map(campo => `${campo}=${form[campo].value}`)
    .join('&');
    
  gtag_report_conversion('https://site.com.br/whatsapp.php?' + queryString)
  return false;
}

function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  console.log('url:', url);
}
```

```html
<form action="whatsapp.php" id="send-whatsapp" target="_blank" method="get">
  <input name="login" type="hidden" value="logindousuario">
  <input name="numero" type="hidden" value="numero">
  <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
  <input type="text" name="telefone" class="telephoneMask" placeholder="(00) 0000-0000">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="enviar" onclick="return onSubmit(this.form, this)">
</form>
```